# Gem Install Rails Giving Error: Failed To Build Gem Native Exension CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, rubygems

I know there are tons of questions like this one, but I looked at all of them I could find and none of them worked.

I just installed CentOS today, so I'm still getting used to how things worked. I installed ruby with this command:

```
sudo yum install ruby
```

Here is the full log:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200719-46896-88vbp9.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nokogiri-1.10.10/gem_make.out
```

I ran `sudo gem update` and `sudo gem update --system`, but both of them gave an error too. For `sudo gem update`, the error message was really long so I put it in a pastebin to not clutter things which you can find [here](https://pastebin.com/vVWjMY6T). For `sudo gem update --system` here is the error message:'

```
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.1.4
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.4
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/share/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.1.4
```

What else do I need to do/install? You can ask me if I installed something in the comments.

Comment: Have you installed the necessary libxml2 and libxslt development headers? `yum install -y libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel`

Comment: @jebentier I have installed all of those, it's still giving me the error.

Comment: @anothermh Sorry for the typo, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue today.
After some curses, I noticed that in gem list there was rubygem-update, but with another path... not in /usr/share/gems/ but in /usr/local/share/gems
So I did

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.1.4/ /usr/share/gems/gems/rubygems-update-3.1.4
```

And everything was fine.